# Unable to run NanoPlot due to import error from Scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, package, importerror, ubuntu-20.04

I am new to python and I'm trying to run NanoPlot 1.40.0 on my Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.
When I try to run NanoPlot I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/grid/.local/bin/NanoPlot", line 5, in <module>
    from nanoplot.NanoPlot import main
  File "/home/grid/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nanoplot/NanoPlot.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._ccallback import LowLevelCallable
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/_lib/_ccallback.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _ccallback_c
ImportError: cannot import name '_ccallback_c' from 'scipy._lib' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/_lib/__init__.py)
```

Some background info; there was an initial Python2.7 and I upgraded to the python3.7 version - made this my default. Scipy was installed using `sudo apt-get install python3-scipy`. The version is Scipy 1.3.3

When I installed NanoPlot, it was done using `pip` and not `pip3` with the `pip install NanoPlot` and then `pip install NanoPlot --upgrade`

After installation, I got this message

> Script nanoplot is installed in home/grid/.local/bin which is not on
> PATH.

So I then edited the path using `nano ~/.bashrc` to include home/grid/.local/bin and executed using `source ~/.bashrc` I checked $PATH to verify the change and the directory was added. But I always receive the callback error. I uninstalled Scipy, reinstalled it, didn't work. Did all the updates, didn't work.

Any help on how I can rectify this callback error would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE: RESOLVED!***

I uninstalled scipy using `sudo apt-get autoremove python3-scipy`

Also did a purge to check if any config files remained `sudo apt-get purge python3-scipy`

Reinstalled scipy using `pip3 install --user scipy`

Did an update `sudo apt-get update`

Uninstalled Nanoplot `pip3 uninstall NanoPlot`

Installed it back `pip3 install NanoPlot`

Did an upgrade `pip3 install NanoPlot --upgrade`

Tested a code `NanoPlot -h`

*Worked!*